# Swift: Fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value (SpriteKit)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I've just started learning to program `iOS` games with `SpriteKit` and I'm a novice to programming (I have only programmed in Java and Swift before this). I started out by doing a tutorial I found online. I'm at the point where I am trying to add a "Game Over" scene, and I keep getting the error

> "Thread 1:EXC-BAD_INSTRUCTION(code=EXC_I386_INVOP,subcode=0x0)"

when I am declaring the `gameOverLabel` constant. It compiles but crashes at run time as soon as the ball hits the bottom of the screen, which is supposed to trigger the 'Game Over' screen.

```
import SpriteKit

let gameOverLabelCategoryName = "gameOverLabel"

class GameOverScene: SKScene {
    var gameWon: Bool = false {

        didSet {
    let gameOverLabel = childNodeWithName(gameOverLabelCategoryName) as! SKLabelNode
            gameOverLabel.text = gameWon ? "Game Won" : "Game Over"
        }
}
    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        if let view = view {
            let gameScene = GameScene.unarchiveFromFile("GameScene") as! GameScene
            view.presentScene(gameScene)
        }
    }
}
```

Also if anyone has suggestions of places I can go to learn more about `SpriteKit`, articles or videos, it would be much appreciated as most things I have found have been in Objective-C and I am doing this in Swift.

[Here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/84341/create-breakout-game-sprite-kit-swift) is the tutorial I have been following..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

childNodeWithName will return nil if a node with that name does not exist. Your code is not checking for this possibility (the as! assumes that it is both not nil and of the appropriate type) so this is causing the crash.

The tutorial asks you to create this 'gameOverLabel' node and name it before creating this code. Check that you did that correctly and that you did not misname it (it is case sensitive  for example).

Comment: Side note: in this case I think not checking in code not unreasonable - the name is constant and once you get it right it will remain correct so adding code to check it every time is probably not worth it. However if you did want to you would unwrap it in a similar way you are unwrapping view, i.e. 'if let gameOverLabel = childNodeWithName(gameOverLabelCategoryName) as? SKLabelNode { ... }'

Comment: I never created the 'gameOverLabel' label node in GameOverScene.sks. That fixed the problem. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are declaring your `gameOverLabelCategoryName` constant *outside* of the scope of the class which looks a bit odd, but *should* be fine. It will be scoped to **`internal`** ([docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AccessControl.html)).

On **line 14**: "`if let view = view {`" you are declaring a constant named `view` which masks the original `self.view` instance. Perhaps that could be confusing the compiler and causing an internal crash?

Comment: Agree with the first point. However 'if let view = view {' is OK (at least in Swift 1.2).